# is it possible in blackberry to post to facebook wall using access token?

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-eclipse-plugin

I want to post a message on the user's facebook wall using access token. But I am not able to do this. Can anyone provide me the code for the same? I already have the access token of the user.

When I am trying this, it is always asking me my credentials to log in to the facebook before posting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cant post a message on the user's facebook wall using access token.

```
ApplicationSettings sett=new ApplicationSettings(NEXT_URL, APPLICATION_ID, APPLICATION_SECRET, USER_PERMISSIONS);
facebook_=Facebook.getInstance(sett);
user = facebook_.getCurrentUser();
```

Then if you want to save the user, then save it. Then

```
 user.publishPost(your post details(link, image title.....));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do `user.publishPost()` to post to a users wall. Check the following code snippet

```
String[] PERMISSIONS = Facebook.Permissions.PUBLISHING_PERMISSIONS;
ApplicationSettings as = new ApplicationSettings(NEXT_URL, APPLICATION_ID,
        APPLICATION_SECRET, PERMISSIONS);
User user;
Facebook fb;
fb = Facebook.getInstance(as);
fb.getCurrentUser(new BasicAsyncCallback() {
            public void onComplete(
                    com.blackberry.facebook.inf.Object[] objects,
                    final java.lang.Object state) {
                user = (User) objects[0];
                log("Posting to wall");

                user.publishPost(message, link, picture, name, caption,
                        description, source, new BasicAsyncCallback() {
                            public void onComplete(String[] values,
                                    java.lang.Object state) {
                                log("Posted successfully to your facebook wall");
                            }
                        }, null);
            }
```

Comment: When I am trying this, it is always asking me my credentials to log in to the facebook before posting.